# Additivity in Log4J2 (2.5)

Tags: java, log4j2

According to the Log4J2 manual at http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html configuring the loggers using

```
...
      <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.foo.Bar" level="trace">
          <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="error">
          <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
      </Loggers>
...
```

and logging a statement like

```
Logger barLogger = LogManager.getLogger(Bar.class);
barLogger.info("A simple info message");
```

should produce the output

> "A simple info message"

However, I am getting the message twice, i.e.

> "A simple info message"
>
> "A simple info message"

and was wondering why? I know that the not specifying  `additivity="false"` for the Bar logger will propagate the message to the root logger as well. However in this case, the log level of the root logger is set to error and as I read the manual should thus not log the message (which has only been logged as "info") again.

Any hints?

**Update:**
I saw the first answer of @rgoers and this seems to be reasonable. However, to me it seems like the documentation at http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html still is either outdated or incorrect. According to the documentation, the program

```
public class MyApp {
 
    // Define a static logger variable so that it references the
    // Logger instance named "MyApp".
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MyApp.class);
 
    public static void main(final String... args) {
 
        // Set up a simple configuration that logs on the console.
 
        logger.trace("Entering application.");
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        if (!bar.doIt()) {
            logger.error("Didn't do it.");
        }
        logger.trace("Exiting application.");
    }
}
 
public class Bar {
  static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Bar.class.getName());
 
  public boolean doIt() {
    logger.entry();
    logger.error("Did it again!");
    return logger.exit(false);
  }
}
```

with log4J2 configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Logger name="com.foo.Bar" level="trace">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Logger>
    <Root level="error">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

should produce the following output

```
17:13:01.540 [main] TRACE com.foo.Bar - entry
17:13:01.540 [main] TRACE com.foo.Bar - entry
17:13:01.540 [main] ERROR com.foo.Bar - Did it again!
17:13:01.540 [main] TRACE com.foo.Bar - exit (false)
17:13:01.540 [main] TRACE com.foo.Bar - exit (false)
17:13:01.540 [main] ERROR MyApp - Didn't do it.
```

However, running this I am getting

```
00:45:49.951 [main] TRACE com.foo.Bar - entry
00:45:49.951 [main] TRACE com.foo.Bar - entry
00:45:49.951 [main] ERROR com.foo.Bar - Did it again!
00:45:49.951 [main] ERROR com.foo.Bar - Did it again!
00:45:49.951 [main] TRACE com.foo.Bar - exit with(false)
00:45:49.951 [main] TRACE com.foo.Bar - exit with(false)
00:45:49.951 [main] ERROR com.foo.MyApp - Didn't do it.
```

i.e. "Did it again!" is logged twice instead of only once as mentioned in the documentation ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Only the log level of the first matching logger is used to accept or deny >the log event. Once it is accepted it will be passed to all the parent >loggers regardless of whatever level they specify.  <strike>I thought the >documentation was pretty clear about that, but perhaps not.</strike>

Any suggestions on how the documentation could feasibly be updated for a clearer understanding of the expected outcome?